# Как посчитать количество блоков внутри каждого отдельного div и добавить класс по условию?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как посчитать количество блоков `div.item` внутри каждого отдельного `div.content` и добавить `div.content` класс, если количество блоков `div.item` именно в нём превышает 3 штуки?

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(el => {
    if (el.querySelectorAll('.item').length > 3)
       el.classList.add("my-class");
});
```

```css
.my-class {
    background: blue;
    color:white;
}


.content {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Берём все элементы `.content` через [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), далее проходим циклом [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) по ним и в каждом получаем элементы `.item` через тот же `.querySelecorAll` и смотрим их количество через [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(function(e){ // Проходим циклом по всем .content
  if(e.querySelectorAll('.item').length > 3) // если в контент .item больше 3х
    e.classList.add('green'); // то .content добавляем класс .green
})
```

```css
.content {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.green .item {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

Аналогичный вариант на **jQuery**

```js
$('.content').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('.item').length > 3)
    $(this).addClass('green')
})
```

```css
.content {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.green .item {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почти синхронно))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, прикольно получилось)

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(el => {
  if (el.childElementCount > 3) el.classList.add('myclass')
})
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```